# How does @Update work in Android Room?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, persistence, android-room

I have data in a Room database that I want to check whether it equals certain data and update a row accordingly, like:

```
if (dataInDatabase.equals(providedData)) { 
      // update existing data.
}
```

The only @PrimaryKey that I have is an auto-generated ID and there are no @ForeignKeys. I know the existing data can only be updated using a @PrimaryKey but the data I check against are not @PrimaryKeys. What'd be the best way to go about this? How do I iterate and use maybe an `.equals()` method to iterate all the data in the database and update certain rows if they satisfy a condition?

Answer (score 0):

Room gives you an opportunity to use the annotations if your queries are simple CRUD (create, read, update and delete) operations. But if you feel like your queries are more specific you have an option to define a method to handle your desired goal and annotate it with `@query()` annotation passing it your SQL query as a  parameter.

Like for your situation you can consider having a method like

```
@query("put your update query here")
udateMytable(String data);   // pass the data to this method as its arguments
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code for update 
There is an annotation available for update `@Update` . That will update your data in database.

e.g.

```
 @Update
    public void updateUsers(User... users);
```